# pyspark UDF output blank

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a question with my UDF function:
I have a data:[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2QPm.png)

I am writing a code to up case the name column:(input john doe->putout: John Doe)

```
@F.udf
def coverCase(Str):
    resStr=""
    arr=str.split(" ")
    for x in arr:
        resStr=resStr+ x[0:1].upper()+x[1:len(x)]+" "
    
    return resStr
df.select(coverCase("name")).show()
```

I have no output
[output screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj09S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"john doe", 21)], ("id", "name", "age"))

@F.udf
def convertCase(str):
    resStr=""
    arr = str.split(" ")
    for x in arr:
       resStr= resStr + x[0:1].upper() + x[1:len(x)] + " "
    return resStr

df.select(convertCase(col("name"))).show()

+-----------------+
|convertCase(name)|
+-----------------+
|        John Doe |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: This answer fixes your issue. But you can use the built-in function (instead of udf), initcap() to achieve the same result. F.initcap('name')